# ERROR in node_modules/ng2-opd-popup/node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d

Tags: angular5

error:
  ERROR in node_modules/ng2-opd-popup/node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts(16,22): error TS2415: Class 'Subject' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable'.  Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
        Type '(operator: Operator) => Observable' is not assignable to type '(operator: Operator) => Observable'.
          Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
            Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'.

```
tsconfig.app.json

{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [] 
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "paths": {
"@angular/": [
"../node_modules/@angular/"
]
} 
}

i have tried this solution 

"paths": {
"@angular/": [
"../node_modules/@angular/"
]
}    

but it doesn't work for me
```

Comment: I had this issue too.

Answer (score 1):

As posted here: https://github.com/opdahlmann/ng2-opd-popup-sample/issues/23
Try removing the folder:

```
$ rm -fr node_modules/ng2-opd-popup/node_modules
```

got it working after.